# В чем разница между Java и JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java

В чем заключается разница между Java и JavaScript?

Новички часто путают эти два совершенно разные языка. Я думаю создать канонический вопрос - ответ объясняющий совершенно разную природу этих языков и то, что по сути у них нет особо ничего общего, кроме названия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript** - это скриптовый, интерпретируемый, функциональный язык программирования.
**Java** - это язык ООП, компилируемый.

**Java** - это самостоятельный язык программирования, который код он превращает в байт-код, который понимают все компьютеры.

**JavaScript** - это одна из реализаций языка `EcmaScript`.

**Java** и **JavaScript** на сегодняшний день одни из популярных языков программирования, т.к. на них можно делать мобильные приложения, сайты фронт-бек-энд и дальше перечислять долго.

**Java** - строго-типизированный, в нём обязательно указывать тип данных переменной
**JavaScript** - слабо-типизированный, в нём не нужно указывать тип данных, нам можно объявить переменную с помощью ключевого слова **let** (**var** - устаревшее).

Примеры кода вывода `Hello, world!`:

Java:

```java
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
console.log("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123310/discussion-on-answer-by-a-br2h-----java--javascript).